# How to change the color of the div based on a value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-class

```
Here are the scripts and style that I used:

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .greater {
        color:#D7E3BF;
        background-color:#D7E3BF;
    }
    .less {
        color:#E5B9B5;
        background-color:#E5B9B5;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp', []);
    app.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.chargeability = [{ date: '15-Sep-13', max: 100, current: 100 },
        { date: '30-Sep-13', max: 60, current: 50 },
        { date: '15-Oct-13', max: 80, current: 20 }];
        $scope.ytd = 122;
    });
```

This is for the gray-colored bar:

```
    app.directive('barsMax', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('value', function (newValue) {
                    // value attribute has changed, re-render              
                    var value = Number(newValue);
                    var dval = value / 3;
                    element.children().remove();
                    while (dval > 0) {
                    element.append('<div id="bar" style="float:left; color:#D8D8D8;    height: 17px;margin-top:7px;background-color:#D8D8D8;">.</div>')
                        dval--;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

This is for the green-colored bar:

```
    app.directive('barsCurrent', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('value', function (newValue) {
                    // value attribute has changed, re-render              
                    var value = Number(newValue);
                    var dval = value / 3;
                    element.children().remove();
                    while (dval > 0) {
                        element.append('<div id="bar" style="float:left; color:green; height: 17px;margin-top:7px;background-color:green;">.</div>')
                        dval--;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

This is the body of the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="charge in chargeability">
    <bars-max style="z-index:-1;float:left;margin-top:-24px;" value="{{charge.max}}"></bars-max>
    <bars-current style="z-index:-1;float:left;margin-top:-24px;" value="{{charge.current}}"></bars-current>
    <div style="clear:both;height:6px;"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to put an:

```
ng-class="{'greater': charge.current >= charge.max, 'less': charge.current < charge.max}"
```

in the barsCurrent directive so that if current is greater than or equal to max it is color avocado green and if current is less than max, it is color pink. However when I placed this ng-class inside the barsCurrent directive, nothing happened.

Can you suggest any solution to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-class="{true: 'greater',false: 'less'}[charge.current >= charge.max]"`

Comment: element.append('<div id="bar" ng-class="{true: 'greater',false: 'less'}[charge.current >= charge.max]" style="float:left; color:green; height: 17px;margin-top:7px;background-color:green;">.</div>') This is what i did and it is not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r8JL7/2/  Check out the fiddle I created to see how it works.

Comment: hi..yes it works if it is on a simple div, however, I need it to work inside the barsCurrent directive

Comment: Ah ok, that is alot different then. You'll need to change it in your directive.  Unfortunately the way you're doing it with `element.append` it won't work with `ng-class` you'll need to rethink how the directive operates.  Try using the `templateUrl` or `template` propoperties of directives.  You'll also want to look at using the `scope` property and `=` for a two way binding of attribute variables.

Comment: is it possible to simply do it this way..in my ng-class I will set the width of a div based on the value of charge.current?so it would be simpler?do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: how will I set width = charge.current?

Comment: how about the width? how can I set the width to be equal to current?thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, hope that last example is more in line with what you were hoping

Comment: oh yes..this is exactly what I would like to accomplish..thanks for the inputs.. this is a good example...

Comment: Hi again, I tried implementing this code..however, it only works for the first time. Not when I am trying to change the value of current/max... The previous color remains the same..example current:100 max:100-green then I change it to current:80 max:90...still color green.. Can you further assist?

Comment: Here try this: http://jsfiddle.net/S7g6b/1/  Notice that in the directive I changed the scope variables from `var = '@'` to `var = '='` this creates a two way binding with the original variable so that when the original changes so does the value in the directive.  Also you'll need to then remove the curly braces `{{}}` around the variables for the directive's element attributes in the HTML partial.  Using curly braces interprets the value of the variables, without the braces the variable is akin to being passed by reference.